# Как нажать на кнопку "Пуск" в windows с помощью win32api или pywinauto

Tags: python, winforms, pywinauto

Мне нужно как-то нажать на кнопку "Пуск". А точнее скрыть появившееся меню.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, показано ли оно в данный момент времени, поэтому нужно именно закрыть его если оно открыто, но не открыть если оно сейчас не открыто.
Желательно с помощью библиотек win32api/pywinauto.
Мне нужно это сделать на windows 11, поэтому это надо сделать способом, который не использует нажатие по координатам.

Из вариантов придумал только отравлять сочетание клавиш win+M, но это скорее костыль, чем решение.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть использовать эмулятор клавиатуры и нажать кнопку win?